# How to create a function to save outputs to a text file?

Tags: c

I am supposed to create a program that given a file with a .vcf extension, read its data and print out a formatted contact sheet. Provided that i was able to do so, how would i be able to save the output to a text file whose name or path is provided by the user?? Just a beginner trying to figure out how to code.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [C file I/O tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)

Basically one way is to combine fopen and fprintf. Basic jist, open a file, write  to it, close it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I wrote you a function. (Your job to include the right includes, header, etc)

```
void save (char * filename)
{
    FILE *output = fopen (filename, "w");
    fprintf (output, "This is a test message");
    fclose(output);
}
```

*I hope I'm not doing this wrong as this is my first stack overflow answer*. But test out this function in your environment of choice as

```
save("outfile.txt");
```

And thats generally the 'jist' of how it works on C. You fopen the file for writing (hence the "w", there are plenty of resources online that will show you your options), you fprintf the message to the output file. and then you close it.

hope that helps!